# Is there a way to do an automatic follow up email with Freeform Pro?

Tags: solspace-freeform, notification

I have a form on a website that offers a free download of a brochure, once submitted. I was wondering if there was a way to send an email notification after 2 days just asking if they were happy with the download?

I didn't know if it was possible to delay the notification somehow so that it was delivered 2 days later, then I could tailor the message accordingly. Or if there is a better way to do this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will require custom development - either by:

1. Using the [freeform_module_user_notification](http://www.solspace.com/docs/freeform/extension_hooks/#freeform_module_user_notification) hook to record elsewhere (likely in a custom database table) that a follow-up is required on a certain date for this particular submission, and then having other custom code send that email when the time comes.
2. Periodically (via a cron job) checking all entries in the relevant Freeform database table for submissions which match your criteria (certain form, and certain length of time passed), and then sending the follow-up via that data.

Hope that helps.

Comment: This helps greatly, I will have to get my developer hat on today I think. Thanks.